# Add a blank row in gridview as value change of a cell

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

i want to add row in gridview as showin link below
http://asp.net-informations.com/gridview/newrow.htm
My question is that in this Aqua line insert after value 6380 but i want Aqua line before 6380 and it shows 6380 and then before 7066 and show 7066 and so on the line insert before value start not after lines

Comment: Just check the `e.Row.RowIndex == 0` in `GridView1_RowCreated` event and if it is then call the `AddNewRow` use the same code that should do it.

Comment: Hii its working now but the thing is it shows blank row i want to show 6380 on top and as 7066 start i want to put 7066 can anyone tell

Comment: Ok so in each empty row you want to show the `6380 ` and `7066` respectively right ?

Comment: yes as cell value change so that value should be there

Comment: In `AddNewRow` method `HeaderCell.Text = storeID` pass the storeID to the `AddNewRow`.

Comment: already done it shows blank first row and so on

Answer (score 0):

```
You can handle this blank row with css and jquery.
```

1.add below code to gridview columns:

```
<asp:TemplateField>
    <ItemTemplate>
 <input id="Hidden1" value='<% Eval("id") %>' type="hidden" />
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>

in this code "id" is unique for every group
```

2.add this code to asp.net page:

```
  <style>           
            .seperate {
                border-bottom: 20px solid #0000cd;
            }

        </style>
        <script>

            $('table tr td input[type=hidden]').each(function () {

                var prev = $(this).closest('tr').prev().find("input[type=hidden]");

              if (prev.val() != $(this).val()) {
                  prev.closest('tr').after("<tr><td colspan='2' class='seperate'></td></tr>");
              }

            });

            $("tr:last").after("<tr><td colspan='2' class='seperate'></td></tr>");
        </script>


in this code you must replace your columns count in colspan.
```